# Ionic tabs auto navigation

Tags: angularjs, navigation, history

The 'auto' back function and 'remember history' function of is pretty nice.

But if I have a link on a page that go directly into another tab's 2nd layer, I will never be able to see the 1st layer of the 2nd tab due to the 'remember history' function.

Here is the codepenproject.

```
http://codepen.io/wildcolor/pen/MYYLVG
```

```
<ion-nav-bar class="nav-title-slide-ios7 bar-positive">
  <ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon ion-arrow-left-c">
  </ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>

<ion-nav-view animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>


<script id="tabs.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-positive">

    <ion-tab title="Home" icon="ion-home" href="#/tab/home">
      <ion-nav-view name="home-tab"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

    <ion-tab title="About" icon="ion-ios7-information" href="#/tab/about">
      <ion-nav-view name="about-tab"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

    <ion-tab title="Contact" icon="ion-ios7-world" ui-sref="tabs.contact">
      <ion-nav-view name="contact-tab"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

  </ion-tabs>
</script>

<script id="home.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-view title="Home">
    <ion-content class="padding">
      <p>Example of Ionic tabs. Navigate to each tab, and
      navigate to child views of each tab and notice how
      each tab has its own navigation history.</p>
      <p>
        <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" ui-sref="tabs.navstack">about navstack</a>
      </p>
      <p>
        <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/facts">Scientific Facts</a>
      </p>
      <p>
        <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" ng-click="getClicky()">get clicky</a>
      </p>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>

<script id="facts.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-view title="Facts" class="padding">
    <ion-content>
      <p>Banging your head against a wall uses 150 calories an hour.</p>
      <p>Dogs have four toes on their hind feet, and five on their front feet.</p>
      <p>The ant can lift 50 times its own weight, can pull 30 times its own weight and always falls over on its right side when intoxicated.</p>
      <p>A cockroach will live nine days without it's head, before it starves to death.</p>
      <p>Polar bears are left handed.</p>
      <p>
        <a class="button icon ion-home" href="#/tab/home"> Home</a>
        <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/facts2">More Facts</a>
      </p>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>

<script id="facts2.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-view title="Also Factual">
    <ion-content class="padding">
      <p>111,111,111 x 111,111,111 = 12,345,678,987,654,321</p>
      <p>1 in every 4 Americans has appeared on T.V.</p>
      <p>11% of the world is left-handed.</p>
      <p>1 in 8 Americans has worked at a McDonalds restaurant.</p>
      <p>$283,200 is the absolute highest amount of money you can win on Jeopardy.</p>
      <p>101 Dalmatians, Peter Pan, Lady and the Tramp, and Mulan are the only Disney cartoons where both parents are present and don't die throughout the movie.</p>
      <p>
        <a class="button icon ion-home" href="#/tab/home"> Home</a>
        <a class="button icon ion-chevron-left" href="#/tab/facts"> Scientific Facts</a>
      </p>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>

<script id="about.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-view title="About">
    <ion-content class="padding">
      <h3>Create hybrid mobile apps with the web technologies you love.</h3>
      <p>Free and open source, Ionic offers a library of mobile-optimized HTML, CSS and JS components for building highly interactive apps.</p>
      <p>Built with Sass and optimized for AngularJS.</p>
      <p>
        <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/navstack">Tabs Nav Stack</a>
      </p>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>

<script id="nav-stack.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-view title="Tab Nav Stack">
    <ion-content class="padding">
      <p><img src="http://ionicframework.com/img/diagrams/tabs-nav-stack.png" style="width:100%"></p>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>

<script id="contact.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-view title="Contact">
    <ion-content>
      <p>@IonicFramework</p>
      <p>@DriftyCo</p>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>
```

If you press the button 'about navstack', you see the 2nd layer of 'about' tab. Because you go directly into the 2nd layer of 'about' tab you will never be able to see the 1st layer of 'about' tab.

To see what the 1st layer of the 'about' tab is, press 'F5' to refresh browse and press the 'about' tab in the middle part of the bottom bar.

how do we solve this?

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you...

You can put

```
<a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" ui-sref="tabs.about">about navstack</a>
```

so it will redirect to the 2nd tab's first layer than from there you can go to tabs nav stack...

Comment: Hi. thanks for the reply. But it wasn't the solution. I got answer from ionic forum. Link http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-tabs-auto-navigation/13052/16